# Cypher unwind and nested CSV data only matching first occurence

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with 2 separate sets of CSV input data, a list of references and a list of documents.
I am building a graphDB to track which document/s depends on which reference/s.
The list of docs CSV file contains nested data for the references which need to be evaluated individually for each doc.

My current cypher only creates the relationship for the first match, the amount of references for each doc varies and could be null, hence the UNWIND and WHERE EXISTS.

I expect a new relationship to be created for each reference with a successful match, not only the first one.
The second reference could result in an unsuccessful match and the third match in the unwind could be successful and so forth for each reference found by the UNWIND.

```
MATCH (doc:ProjectLibrary) WHERE EXISTS(doc.`References:DocumentIDValue`)
UNWIND split(doc.`References:DocumentIDValue`,';') AS reference
MATCH(n:Reference_Verified {DocumentID: reference}) 
MERGE(doc)-[:References]->(n)
```

Is the iteration stopped when an unsuccessful match is made?

I am still thinking in terms of for loops so these single row queries take some getting use to.

[UPDATE]

Following up on a comment, it turns out the second and following items contain a preceding '#' which would result in the match failing.

Although this newer query solves the '#', the end result is unchanged:

```
MATCH (doc:ProjectLibrary) WHERE EXISTS(doc.`References:DocumentIDValue`)
UNWIND split(doc.`References:DocumentIDValue`,';') AS reference
WITH REPLACE(reference,"#","") AS refclean 
MATCH(n:Reference_Verified {DocumentID: refclean})
MERGE(doc)-[:References]->(n)
```

Comment: Do you have any whitespace that need to be trimmed from the ends of the `reference` elements?

Comment: No whitespace, but after careful inspection, the second and following items contain a preceding # which would result in the match failing.

Comment: ```WITH REPLACE(reference,"#","") AS refclean``` together with ```MATCH(n:Reference_Verified {DocumentID: refclean}) ``` solves the # but the end result is unchanged

Comment: I updated your question with the new info.

Comment: 1. Your `REPLACE` will replace all "#"; do any of the elements internally contain "#"? 2. Are you sure that `refclean` matches existing `Reference_Verified` nodes? 3. Do the wanted `References` relationships already exist (`MERGE` will not create duplicates)?

Comment: The "#" are just an annoying byproduct of a sharepoint nesting the references. I've managed to solve my initial problem but by cleaning out the annoying "#" manually. A cypher solution for dealing with the annoying "#" would be ideal.

Comment: You should create a new question with the details of the '#' issue. Cypher (possibly with the help of APOC library) should be able to cleanse data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a subquery? something like ...

```
MATCH (doc:ProjectLibrary) WHERE EXISTS(doc.`References:DocumentIDValue`)
UNWIND split(doc.`References:DocumentIDValue`,';') AS reference
call
{
with reference
MATCH(n:Reference_Verified {DocumentID: reference}) 
return n
}
MERGE(doc)-[:References]->(n)
```

Subqueries can be nested if you are trying to link documents.

Comment: I am on ver 3.4, hence the CALL function is not available...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue (based on data without the offending "#") with some inspiration from [Merge Nodes and Relationship](https://community.neo4j.com/t/merge-nodes-and-relationship/22577/14)

Using UNWIND with RANGE and an iterator provides the for loop I needed:

```
MATCH (doc:ProjectList) WHERE EXISTS(doc.ReferencesDocumentIDValue)
WITH SPLIT(doc.ReferencesDocumentIDValue,';') AS refID_split, doc
UNWIND range(0, size(refID_split)) AS i
MATCH (ref:Reflist) WHERE ref.DocumentID = refID_split[i]
MERGE (doc)-[:references]->(ref)
```